# Array Formation Issue

Tags: mysql

I am running an SQL Query in order to get the post IDs of the user currently logged in.

My query works as designed.

```
$userGadgets = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT item_id FROM mg_gd_mylist WHERE user_id = '$user_id'", ARRAY_A);
```

The issue I am facing has to do with the array returned.

```
array(
16
) {
[0]=> array(
1
) {
[\"item_id\"]=> string(
5
) \"10318\" }
[1]=> array(
1
) {
[\"item_id\"]=> string(
5
) \"10378\" }
[2]=> array(
1
) {
[\"item_id\"]=> string(
5
) \"10566\" }
[3]=> array(
1
) {
[\"item_id\"]=> string(
5
) \"10608\" }
[4]=> array(
1
) {
[\"item_id\"]=> string(
5
) \"10614\" }
```

The model I am trying to produce is the following

```
Array
(
    [0]  => 140 //The item_id string as an integer


    [1] => 141


    [2] => 142

)
```

Any ideas on that one ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use a custom post type and `WP_Query` with the author field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things going on here.

**First**, you're getting back a multidimensional array ([array of arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)) where the nested arrays have column names as keys. The reason for this is your use of the `ARRAY_A` parameter. You can read about the output types in [the codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results). You may be just fine using the default `OBJECT`. I'm going to answer as you have it though.

**Second**, the values of the nested arrays are SQL escaped strings.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381316/8015265) gives a good explanation as to why the result is escaped and suggests the `stripslashes();` to fix it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323169/8015265) gives a good explanation as to why strings come back instead of integers. It suggests typecasting or a PHP function but I would use the WordPress function [absint()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/absint) to make sure I had a non-negative integer.

So you could use something like this to achieve your desired outcome:

```
function wpsx_make_item_id_to_int($userGadgets) {
    //Init out collection array
    $item_id_ints = array();

    //Process parent array
    foreach ($userGadgets as $key => $array) {
        //Process nested arrays
        foreach ($array as $column_name => $column_value) {
            //$column_value is your item_ids
            if (is_string($column_value)) {
                //Make ID into int and add it to our colection
                $item_id_ints[] = absint(stripslashes($column_value));
            }
        }
    }
    //Return an associative array of (int)item_ids
    return $item_id_ints;
}
```

However are you sure you need to be using $wpdb in the first place? I find most of the time you can achieve what you need to by leveraging built in WordPress functionally and API's with the added benefit of a bit more ease and security.